# Dynamically update expiry date based on a previous date using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysqli

I want supply the effective date(initial date) and the system automatically add one(1) year to the date supplied above, using JavaScript or any other better method.

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
    <p>
        <strong style="color:black">Software Name:</strong>
        <input type="text" name="swname" value=""  />
    </p>&nbsp;

    <p>
        <strong style="color:black"> 
            Company 
            <input type="text" name="coy" size="50" value="">
        </strong>
    </p>&nbsp;

    <p>
        <strong style="color:black"> 
            Effective Date 
            <input type="date" name="sdate" value="" onblur="getYearVal();" />
        </strong>
    </p>&nbsp;

    <script>
        function getYearVal() {
            //script that automatically add one year to the above is placed here
        }
    </script>

    <p>    
        <strong style="color:black"> 
            Expiry Date
            <input type="date" name="edate"  id="edate"  value=""/>
        </strong>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register " /> | 
        <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Cancel" /> 

</form>
```

Comment: Are you wanting to update a mysql record? or just update the value in the textbox?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create a [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

`var date = new Date('year','month','day');`

Then add 1 year:

`date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() + 1);`

This is just an example, modify it according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is the getFullYear() js function

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getFullYear();
```

source here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getfullyear.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a value to input you should at least select it. Here you can use either [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) or [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

To set a value of element just use [value propery](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-value)

And finally check out [Date javascript object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

code that should do things:

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <p><strong style="color:black">Software Name:</strong>
    <input type="text" name="swname" value="" />
  </p>
  <p><strong style="color:black">Company</strong> 
    <input type="text" name="coy" size="50" value="">
  </p>
  <p><strong style="color:black">Effective Date</strong> 
    <input type="date" name="sdate" value="" />
  </p>
  <p><strong style="color:black">Expiry Date</strong>
    <input type="date" name="edate" id="edate" value="" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register " />|
    <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Cancel" />
  </p>

  <script>
    var date = new Date(),
      dateString = (date.getFullYear() + 1) + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate();
    document.querySelector('input[name="sdate"]').value = dateString;
  </script>

</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, however, the expiry date is not correct. E.g 29/04/2015 adding one year shld be 28/04/2016 but it is given 29/04/2015. shld I subtract 1 from the month or what is the best way

Comment: Hm. For me my example gives "2016/5/5" as the result. Probably you are doing something wrong there.